# how to get the 100 days before date from Todays Date in Dimdatedimension

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I have small doubt in ssas cube datasource view level.
I want add one new column(last100days) in Dimdate timension and that column show last 100 days information.
I Tried in sql server level like below query
add new column(last100days) in dimdate dimension
1)update dimdate set last100days='01-01-1900'
2)`update dimdate
set last100days=[StandardDate]
WHERE [StandardDate] >= DATEADD(day,-100, getdate())
and   [StandardDate] <= getdate()`

That time i  will get  accurate result in dimdate dimension.
same way I tried In datasoure view level in dimdatedimension level right click on that and choose new namedcalculation  and I give column name is last100days and enter expression like 
[StandardDate] >= DATEADD(day,-100, getdate())
and   [StandardDate] <= getdate()
that time it show error like below

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Deferred prepare could not be completed.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'update'.

---

BUTTONS:

OK..I

  -

---

```
enter code here
```

---

add new column and that column have from today to last100 days dates .please help me how to resolve this issuse in ssas cube side

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter an expression that returns a value.   All yours does is test conditions.

Try this instead:

```
CASE 
  WHEN  [StandardDate] >= DATEADD(day,-100, getdate()) AND [StandardDate] <= getdate()
       THEN [StandardDate]
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: hi is it possible retrive only last 100days for that column without null values. i mean suppose  standared date columns havelast 110 dates.but we disply last100days column only last 100days remain 10 column have null values.finaly i want in expression retrive without null values records .please tell me how to write expresion to retrvie last100day information without null or emptyp values

Comment: What is the name of the column that you want to test for NULL?

Comment: I want create one measure  that is last100day in dimdate dimension. cube side  to see amount information for last 100days.that time  i drag and drop last100days attribut/measure on cube side.that time some columns came null/empty and  coresping amount infomation.reason for null came that date not avilable last 100day so its came.now I donot want display that null infomation in cube side.only need  last100day information no need null related infomation.please tell me how resolve it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment above.  Maybe you should edit your question so you can word it more clearly with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to create a measure for this. You need a new column in your date dimension to be indicative of whether the date is older than 100 days or not. Let's say that column is called `RollingLast100days`. You need to make a minor adjustment to @tab-alleman's code.

```
CASE 
  WHEN  DATEDIFF(dd, [StandardDate], GETDATE()) <=100
       THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Now that the column is ready, if you want to see only last 100 days worth of data, you just need to have a small additional condition.

```
WHERE [Dim Date].[Date].RollingLast100days = 1
```

e.g. Fetching the sales for the last 100 days only:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON 0
FROM    [YourCube]
WHERE [Dim Date].[Date].RollingLast100days = 1
```

Fetching a list of products sold in the last 100 days:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON 0,
Product.Products.MEMBERS ON 1
FROM    [YourCube]
WHERE [Dim Date].[Date].RollingLast100days = 1
```

Hope this helps.